# Run ServiceOperation with generics?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, delegates

**Hi,**

I have a Sevice with a alot of operations, I need to wrapp the call inside a special method on the client side that tries to reconnect if the call fails.

My serviceoperations do always looks like this :

```
[MySpecialResponse] MyServiceOperation([MySpecialRequest] request)
```

And I need a method like this (Pseudocode) :

```
DoServiceCall<MySpecialResponse>(MyServiceOperation(request));

public T DoServiceCall<T>(ServiceMethod)
{
   return ServiceMethod(request);
}
```

Im not sure how to do this with generics, pleas help.

Comment: Doesen't sound that generic to me

Comment: Okay, but how could I solve it? All I need is to wrap the service call to beable to handle communication problems. It would be great if I could avoid adding logic to all my ServiceAgents.

Comment: What range of types does MyServiceOperation return?

Comment: Are [MySpecialResponse] and [MySpecialRequest] types, placeholders for a generic type or attributes?

Comment: Its regular classes with datacontract attributes(attributes does not matter here I supose). There is no basecalss but I could add it if makes it easier.

Comment: The return object is always a regular response object(DataContract)

Comment: I found this that looks the right way but Im not sure how to implement this in to my solution where I got no baseclasses for the request and response objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to do somthing like

```
public TResult DoServiceCall<T, TResult>(Func(T, TResult) operation, T request)
{
    // Your wrapping here
    return operation(request);
    // and here?
}
```

So, you would use it like this.

```
MySpecialResponse response = DoServiceCall(MyServiveOperation, request)
```

If you have service operations that take a different number of parameters you would need to overload `DoServiceCall` accordingly.

**EDIT**

I wrote this console app to prove it works

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DoServiceCall(times2, 5));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static TResult DoServiceCall<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> operation,
                                                    T request)
    {
        return operation(request);
    }

    private static int times2(int x)
    {
        return 2 * x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pleas, specifie what information you need more. I have tried to copy/paste your solution but its not working, it is complaining about Using the generic type 'System.Func<TResult>' requires 1 type arguments.

Comment: Im using .net 4.0. I have tried this > public R Execute<T, R>(this T client, Func<R> serviceFunc)
            where T : My.ServiceContracts.IMyClientService and that method head works fine.

Comment: The generic `Func` declaration includes a type for each parameter and finally a type for the return value. So the definition in your comment defines a `Func` that returns `R` and takes no parameters.